# When use Extension class, when use Compiler Passes in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

What is the point of using compiler passes in Symfony?

When we should use Extension class and when Compiler Passes in Symfony?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html & http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class

Comment: these links say how, not why and when. anyway thanks for reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They come with services definition.

By creating a compiler pass, you are able to update the arguments passed to services.

It's most often done with tagged services.

Also, It can be used for :

- Creating new services that require information about other defined services before being defined.
- Swapping or adding arguments to a service that you did not write.
- Creating and modifying parameters in the container.

I used a compiler pass to register a Factory that make me able to override the doctrine Repository.

You can see the code for more comprehension of how it works:

https://gist.github.com/chalasr/77be8eee5e3ecd3c06ec

**Update**

Thank's to @Sruj, I added the part I've forgotten about the `Extension`

`Extension` are part of dependency injection too, especially of the configuration.
Its primary role is to load the configuration of services across the bundles of your application.

Instead of load your configuration manually by using `imports`, you can create an extension that does it for you. All your services configuration are registered from your bundle and shared in your whole application.

When you register a vendor in your app configuration, the service container extension of the vendor is invoked.

See ["Importing configuration via container extensions"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions) part of the documentation

Comment: i accept your answer but i still need to dig deeper into extension as furthermore loading and registering configuration the extension might do much more, like in here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FOSRestExtension.php or here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FOSElasticaExtension.php or here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FOSUserExtension.php

Comment: All code in links consist into loading of services configurations. It also understand to be part of the configuration by setting arguments and definitions of the loaded services, naming/organize them. There is the main difference between the compiler pass which allow to update already configured services that you did not write .